# Extracting data from nested dict in ansible with conditional checks in the list?

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible, nested

I'm stuck with the following issue.
My JSON data looks like this:

```json
[
   {
      "clusters":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "name":"cluster1"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"cluster2"
         }
      ],
      "tag":"a"
   },
   {
      "clusters":[
         {
            "id":"3",
            "name":"cluster2"
         }
      ],
      "tag":"b"
   }
]
```

What I am trying to do is extracting the `tag` values which are connected to a certain cluster (say, `cluster1`). So, I need to check if `cluster1` is in the list of `clusters[*].name` somehow.

Here is my playbook:

```yaml
- name: "Test"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
  - test:
        - clusters:
            - name: "cluster1"
              id: "1"
            - name: "cluster2"
              id: "2"
          tag: "a"
        - clusters:
            - name: "cluster2"
              id: "3"
          tag: "b"

  - set_fact:
      tags_test: "{{ test | community.general.json_query('[?clusters[].name==`cluster1`].tag') }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ tags_test }}"
```

What I am expecting to get is the tag value: `"a"`.

This is the result:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": []
}
```

I also tried combining `json_query` with `selectattr`, but, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JMESPath you have to nest your conditions because you are looking for an object named `cluster1` inside the the JSON array `clusters` which is nested in another array:

```
[?clusters[?name==`cluster1`]].tag|[0]
```

So as a task,

```yaml
- set_fact:
    tags_test: >-
      {{ test | community.general.json_query(
           '[?clusters[?name==`cluster1`]].tag|[0]'
      ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the dictionary of the tags and clusters first

```yaml
  tag_clusters: "{{ test|json_query(tag_clusters_query)|items2dict }}"
  tag_clusters_query: '[].{key: tag, value: clusters[].name}'
```

gives

```yaml
  tag_clusters:
    a:
    - cluster1
    - cluster2
    b:
    - cluster2
```

Then, *selectattr* and *map* the key(s)

```yaml
  tags_test: "{{ tag_clusters|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value', 'contains', 'cluster1')|
                 map(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  tags_test:
  - a
```